# VueJS Google Charts not loading

Tags: vue.js

As the title says, code only loads with static data but when I pass data through props then I just get nothing. When I change the data value (without reloading) Vue will show the data.

My current code:

```
<script>
    import { GChart } from 'vue-google-charts'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                chartData: [
                    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
                    ['2014', 10.50, 400, 200]
                ],
                chartOptions: {
                    chart: {
                        title: 'Company Performance',
                        subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        components: {
            GChart
        },
        props: [
            'usedPercentage',
            'freePercentage'
        ]
    }
</script>
```

I guess, on create() or what ever other hook, the chart has already been rendered and therefore it was unable to insert the data from my props.

How can I still render it properly? and why does this happen?

P.S. when I console log my prop inside a "created" hook, it returns a "function Number()" instead of the real data... ???

Comment: What if you use the redrawChart function https://github.com/haydenbbickerton/vue-charts/blob/master/examples/redraw.html

Comment: I am using Google Charts, that aint Google charts haha :)

Comment: Ok, not sure but may be this https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/8893e9